# oracle CLOB modify to obtain columns for json_table()

Tags: json, oracle, concatenation

Since oracle does not support dynamic conversion of JSON column keys as relational column and JSON column value as relational column value, I had thought to generate my dynamic list of columns as CLOB column

```
col_a,col_b,col_c,col_d
```

and then convert it into below form

```
col_a NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_a',col_b NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_b',col_c NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_c',col_d NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_d'
```

Basically each of my column "col_a" is converted to "col_a NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_a'"

so that I can directly place this clob value in my plsql block and fetch like below

```
select t.*,jt.*
from 
table_1 t,
json_table(t.json_doc,'$' columns (col_a NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_a',col_b NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_b',col_c NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_c',col_d NUMBER(22,3) PATH '$.col_d'))jt
```

but I'm not sure if i can do it using REPLACE or any other function.
I'm able to achieve it by concatenating while generating the original list of dynamic columns, but that additional burden I want to avoid.

NOTE: All columns are NUMBER(22,3) datatypes so not a burden on that side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CLOB is valid JSON, you may be able to retrieve the keys for your CLOB using the function `json_dataguide`. Below is an example

**My Table**

```
create table json_doc (
    data clob check (data is json)
);

insert into json_doc(data) values ('{"col1": "A"}');
insert into json_doc(data) values ('{"col2": "B"}');
```

**Checking the table**

```
select doc.data from json_doc doc;
--   DATA
-- 1 {"col1": "A"}
-- 2 {"col2": "B"}
```

**Then using json_dataguide**

```
select json_dataguide(doc.data) columns from json_doc doc;
--   COLUMNS
-- 1 [{"o:path":"$","type":"object","o:length":16},{"o:path":"$.col1","type":"string","o:length":1},{"o:path":"$.col2","type":"string","o:length":1}]
```

**Finally, using json_table**

```
select jt.* from 
    (select json_dataguide(doc.data) columns from json_doc doc) d, 
    json_table(d.columns, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        path varchar2(22) path '$."o:path"'
    )) jt
--   PATH
-- 1 $
-- 2 $.col1
-- 3 $.col2
```

You can then get the JSON keys including the root (which you can easily remove as well as the `$.` in the beginning, perhaps using `LTRIM`).
If this solves your problem, remember to mark it as the answer ;)